# Transform scale "Zoom" on hover with max width?

Tags: html, css

EDIT:: Resolved, rather than using transform, changing the background-size worked, thank you all.

I am trying to transform the scale of one of the divs while keeping a max width, like a zoom effect, however it ignores the max width?

```css
.Img2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box2 {
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: black;
}
.box2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

```html
<li class="Img2">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting, I didn't know how to create snippets.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MDN article on CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms):

> By modifying the coordinate space, CSS transforms change the shape and position of the affected content without disrupting the normal document flow.

This is why your `transform: scale()` is not affected by your `max-width` constraint. Instead, you'll want to `scale` the height (Y dimension) while keeping the width (X dimension) the same ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)). See updated example below:

```css
.Img2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box2 {
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: black;
}
.box2:hover {
    transform: scale(1, 1.03);
}
```

```html
<li class="Img2">
    <div class="box2"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: And how can i keep the height the same as well? so it does a sort of zoom effect?

Comment: If you keep the width and height the same, then what are you expecting to change? What do you mean by "zoom" effect? Are you talking about animating your scale?

Comment: It would work better if there was a background image, I am looking for a code that will "Scale" or zoom the image within the constraints.

Comment: My bad figured it out with a different method, "background-size"